# GTK3 theme: Where are these colours located in css

Tags: themes, gtk3

Can someone please tell me where the following colours are located in the css:

- the separators in the menus
- the separation line for gEdit when "Display right margin at column..." is checked in preferences
- same gEdit, the left margin when "Display line numbers" is checked.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I have found the answers. The first is in `.menuitem.separator` , in the theme's css, and the last two are in gEdit's .xml colour settings file, names are `right-margin` and `line-numbers`.